# Getting GeoServer to run on Web server

Tags: geoserver, apache

After help from @iant, @dariapra, @RK, & @rangvald, as the combination of setting up the GeoServer Proxy in the interface, and making changes to the Apache-HTTP and Tomcat worked. I can now click on the OpenLayers and a new window pops up with a blank image within the map surrounding box, all within out IP Address.

However, solving one issue raised another.

I now need to fix the new pop up window (after I click the OpenLayers from the Layer Preview pane) in order to show the map that is to be displayed. Within the window, there is the bounding box, text in the bottom left hand corner "Click on the map to get feature info" as well as the bottom right hand corner "location", and in the IE window, the bottom left identifies a yield sign with paper behind it saying "errors occurred".

Is there a way to set this up so the map shows within the new pane after clicking the OpenLayers?

My initial question was: How do I configure GeoServer to show my shapefiles/maps on my Webserver(a specific location as http://www.name.net/geoserver) at work, and not on the localhost:8080?
The web server is running Apache and also tried the Tomcat install.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote up my [notes](http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver_docs/software/index.html) on how to do this on a Linux box (but the process is similar on a windows machine). Specifically you need to have [Apache redirect the requests to the tomcat](http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver_docs/software/java.html#configure-apache-httpd-to-proxy-to-from-tomcat) at localhost:8080 - you need to edit a couple of files.

Comment: Looks like the notes site is down. Can you update, or post the contents here?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to said by @iant, I have managed to make my layers publicly available by going to 'Global Settings' in GeoServer's administration interface and setting the 'Proxy Base URL'.

[image: GeoServer administration, setting proxy base URL]

Answer (score -1):

As long as you do not have anything installed on port 8080 the [default instructions for installation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/index.html) on the geoserver pages should be sufficient. Geoserver is relatively non-intrusive.

If you are looking for a full package with PostGIS and other relevant tools [OpenGeoSuite](http://opengeo.org/products/suite/) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

substitute your ip address for localhost, enable remote connection, open a port that corresponds to your server config.