# Accessing GeoServer on my own domain

Tags: geoserver, ubuntu, proxy, apache, tomcat

I am running GeoServer 2.4.3 on Ubuntu Server 12.04 and tomcat7 and I want to access it on mydomain.com. I have searched a lot and found the all the solutions suggest to use a ProxyPass. One of the posts on GIS Stack Exchange that has a similar problem is [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37514/how-do-i-get-geoserver-to-run-on-my-webserver?rq=1) but the website to the solution provided in the post is down!

This is what I have been doing so far:

Added the follwing to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

```
 ServerName mydomain.com
 ProxyRequests Off
 ProxyPreserveHost On

 <Proxy *>
     Order deny,allow 
     Allow from all 
 </Proxy>
 ProxyPass /geoserver http://servername:8080/geoserver
 ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://servername:8080/geoserver
```

Then I have edited `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml`

```
<context-param>
      <param-name>PROXY_BASE_URL</param-name>
      <param-value>http://mydomain.com:8080/geoserver/</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Finally, I have added In GeoServer > Global Settings > Proxy Base URL >

http://mydomain.com:8080/geoserver/

Now, when I am trying to enter mydomain.com:8080/geoserver I get Unable to connect error!

What I have been doing wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: "Unable to connect" or "Not found" is exactly what I would expect if port 8080 is closed to the external network. I don't understand why are you setting a ProxyPass in Apache (supposedly running on port 80) and then try to access Geoserver through port 8080.

Comment: Try to follow carefully the steps in the link bellow. For me this is a well tested, working solution:

http://www.gistutor.com/geoserver/21-intermediate-geoserver-tutorials/38-configuring-geoserver-proxy-for-public-and-remote-data-access.html

Answer (score 3):

Ciao,
maybe I overlooked something but from the outside you are accessing

http://mydomain.com/geoserver/

not

http://mydomain.com:8080/geoserver/

as the default port for Apache HTTP is port 80, hence connecting to  port 8080 on it would give you exactly that error.

Regards,
Simone.

Answer (score 1):

the port you are trying to connect (8080) is probably closed for outgoing network access.
you may check that from your workstation, by opening cmd(in case of windows) and write the follwing command [netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat):

> netstat 1 -na | find "SYN"

on the raws bellow, you shall see all the network fails