# Access GeoServer from Amazon EC2 to mydomain.com

Tags: geoserver, server, proxy, amazon-ec2

DONE SUCCESSFULLY:

1. I've installed Apache HTTP and Tomcat on Amazon WS (AWS) EC2 instance (MS Windows Server 2012 R2 64 bit).
2. I've deployed GeoServer .WAR file on Tomcat; port 8080.
3. I've added inbound TCP rule in Security Group of AWS to allow port 80 and 22 for Apache and SSH respectively. TCP rule for RDP, Port 3389 is allowed by default in Inbound.
4. I can access GeoServer from 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web' on server machine.
5. Firewall on Windows Server is disabled fot both Private and Public.

I want to access GeoServer from my sub-domain 'www.geotool.mydomain.com'.

TRIED BUT FAILED:

1. Followed [these instructions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37514/how-do-i-get-geoserver-to-run-on-my-webserver?rq=1); entered my sub-domain 'www.geotool.mydomain.com' in Proxy Base URL, but I get timed out error.
2. Can't access GeoServer from Server IP, 'http://10.129.13.8:8080/geoserver' either.

Can someone please guide me?

Comment: You'll probably need to clarify what "didn't work" means (use the "edit" button)

Comment: Try adding a custom TCP rule to the security group to allow access to 8080.

Comment: what is the external ip or domain of your aws server? I dont think that it is `10.129.13.8`

Comment: Well AWS Server IP keeps changing everytime I log in.